# ASP.NET Identity: UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword keeps failing

Tags: entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2 with Entity Framework 5 (because our Oracle data provider does not support EF6). For some reason the password verification by means of `UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword` keeps failing.

My `UserStore` class contains:

```
    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(IccmUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        IPasswordHasher hasher = new PasswordHasher();

        var t = Task.Run(() => {
            user.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(passwordHash);
        });
        return t;
    }
```

The (obviously hashed) password is stored in the database. Thus, this code seems to work just fine.

My `AccountController` does the password verification like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(SignInModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            // This fails:
            //var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);

            // Thus: do it step by step.
            PasswordVerificationResult result = PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;

            // Step 1: find user.
            IccmUser user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            if (user == null) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Couldn't find the user.");
            } else {
                // Step 2: validate password
                result = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.PasswordHash, model.Password);
                if (result != PasswordVerificationResult.Success) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The password is not valid.");
                } else {
                    // Step 3: sign-in user.
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The `VerifyHashedPassword()` in step 2 always returns `Failed`. Both parameters (`PasswordHash` and `Password`) are passed in correctly.

Any pointers to what I'm missing are greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK, another look after a short break reveals: SetPasswordHashAsync() already receives the password as hashed from UserManager.CreateAsync(). Thus, I shouldn't hash it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the UserStore implementation. `SetPasswordHashAsync()` is not supposed to hash the password. Instead, it receives the hashed password from `UserManager.CreateAsync()`. Thus, the following change in `UserStore` does the trick:

```
    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(IccmUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash = passwordHash);
    }
```

Sorry for the noise.